# Insert custom content in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some problem in WooCommerce Admin Order menu. I want to add some content in the column but I don't know where I can make it.

This is some example screenshoot about my woocommerce admin order view :

[image]

I want to add phone number bellow email address in Order column.

Please help me to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this once, i've followed this tutorial :

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen--wp-24934

Comment: Is that same if I'm doing in WooCommerce ?

Comment: I think, an order is a custom post type `order`, you must add a statement to exclude other post type.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'match_order_woocommerce_custom_order_columns', 2);

function match_order_woocommerce_custom_order_columns( $column ) {

remove_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'woocommerce_custom_order_columns', 2);

global $post, $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order( $post->ID );

switch ($column) {

    case "order_title" :

        if ($order->user_id) $user_info = get_userdata($order->user_id);

        if (isset($user_info) && $user_info) :

            $user = '<a href="user-edit.php?user_id=' . esc_attr( $user_info->ID ) . '">';

            if ($user_info->first_name || $user_info->last_name) $user .= $user_info->first_name.' '.$user_info->last_name;
            else $user .= esc_html( $user_info->display_name );

            $user .= '</a>';

        else :
            $user = __('Guest', 'woocommerce');
        endif;

        echo '<a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit').'"><strong>'.sprintf( __('Order %s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ).'</strong></a> ' . __('made by', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . $user;

        if ($order->billing_email) :
            echo '<small class="meta">'.__('Email:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . '<a href="' . esc_url( 'mailto:'.$order->billing_email ).'">'.esc_html( $order->billing_email ).'</a></small>';
        endif;
        if ($order->billing_phone) :
            echo '<small class="meta">'.__('Tel:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . esc_html( $order->billing_phone ) . '</small>';
        endif;

    break;

}
}
```

Please try this snippet in your active theme's functions.php